# Reference to shared project in TFS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm working with a lot of console applications, and all of them use a shared project. The branch in TFS looks like this:

```
-branchname
   --scripts
   --sharedlib
   --applications
        --application1
        --application2 etc.
```

There are hundreds of applications which all reference the project inside **sharedlib**. And we're not referencing **.dll** from it, because some application teams would want to customize the shared project.

So for all the applications to work, I've mapped the TFS branch to my local and open the solution and add an existing project and add the shared project *.csproj* as a reference *(in Visual Studio 2015)*.
I can see the reference to the shared project in both the *.sln* and *.csproj* file of my applications which goes like:

```
..\..\sharedlib\commonproject\commonproject.csproj
```

Meaning it goes two levels up from the application solution folder, finds that **sharedlib** folder and subsequently the *.csproj* file. It works fine on the local.

But when I create a build definition for the application in **TFS 2015**, it all blows up. Because the TFS build **"Get Sources"** step brings the **sharedlib** folder to the *.sln* folder level as the Repository Mapping in TFS is made for both the **application folder** and **sharedlib** folder to the *$(build.sourcesDirectory)* and *$(build.sorcesDirectory)\sharedlib* path respectively. So when it looks at the *.sln* file and tries to go two levels up to find the shared project *.csproj* file, it simply won't be able to do that because in the build server the common *.csproj* file is at one level down from where the *.sln* files are copied to: 
`(sharedlib\commonproject\commonproject.csproj)`

So If I edit the .sln and .csproj file to remove the two levels up path and simply put it as `(sharedlib\commonproject\commonproject.csproj)`, then it builds on the server, but won't even load on the local as the path becomes incorrect in the local. So I can't seem to make it work on both local and TFS server.

**Is there any way to fix this problem?**

One possible solution that I can think of is copying the shared project two levels up in the build server before it starts the build and keep the path in the *.sln* and *.csproj* untouched. But how can I design that step in TFS?

Any kind of solution would be greatly appreciated.

***Thank You***

Comment: Not sure how it works in TFS or if you are using git, but in VSTS you can achieve this using git submodules.

Answer (score 0):

"Some application teams would want to customize the shared project." They could also generate multiple versions of dll based on the shared project, and use Nuget to manage/import the version they need.

If your team insist on using project reference instead of dll reference. Suggest you use **Relative path** reference instead of using absolute path.

Since it's  two levels up from the application solution folder, you could try to use

```
$(SolutionDir)\sharedlib\commonproject\commonproject.csproj
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank You for the answer. But since the common project folder is up 2 levels from the solution folder, the commonproject.csproj is not going to be inside the solution directory.

Comment: I solved this using a _File Copy_ task in Build Definition to copy 'commonproject' folder 2 levels up from the solution folder. So that the location of shared project that is mentioned in the .sln file (eg: `..\..\sharedlib..`) is satisfied in the build server as well, So it builds. But I've run into a different problem now: I can't seem to find $(build.sourcesDirectory)\bin\Release folder. Even when I set a output dir for the MSBuild for my solution, I only get .dlls for the common project and the dlls and .exe for my project are nowhere to be found, even though the build succeeds.

Comment: @AshK  BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. For example: `c:\agent\_work\1\s` . Since your build succeeds, you could check your build log or directly remote to build agent machine and check where is your generated project dll  located. Besides, suggest you add a screenshot of your project/solution folder level in Visual Studio, you make me a little more confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the local path of the projects on Build Agent Folder in the build definition. The easy way I would prefer is setting the path two level down for application project in the build definition like following and then update the path in VS Build step accordingly:

```
Application: $(build.sourcesDirectory)\app\app 
Sharedlib: $(build.sorcesDirectory)\sharedlib
```